# borrar el texto introducido en un textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente textarea:

```
<div class=" input-field col s11 m6 l4 push-s1 push-m3 push-l4 formdivB ">
  <textarea id="textarea1" rows="1" class=" materialize-textarea textoinput1 colortextoB"></textarea>
  <label id="Pbusc"for="textarea1" class=" textoinput modal-trigger"href="#modal3">Pbusc </label>
  <i id="lupa1" onclick="buscarpaciente()" class="material-icons posicionlupa">search</i>
</div>
```

Cuando escribo en el textarea puedo leerlo mediante:

```
var textoabuscar=document.getElementById('textarea1').value;

console.log(textoabuscar);
```

El problema es que no consigo borrar el texto introducido por código... he probado con

```
var limpio=document.getElementById('textarea1');
limpio = '';
limpio = "";
```

pero no se borra... se queda sin `value` pero en la visualización html no se quitan las letras...

Answer (score 1):

Para borrar el texto, he creado un botón llamado "**Borrar**" en el archivo **.html** de tal forma que llama a una función la cual borra el texto de tu textArea en el archivo **.js**.

```js
function borrarTexto() {
    document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
            <div class=" input-field col s11 m6 l4 push-s1 push-m3 push-l4 formdivB ">
          
          <textarea id="textarea1" rows="1" class=" materialize-textarea textoinput1 colortextoB"></textarea>
          <label id="Pbusc"for="textarea1" class=" textoinput modal-trigger"href="#modal3">Pbusc </label>
          <i id="lupa1" onclick="buscarpaciente()" class="material-icons posicionlupa">search</i>
          <input type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="borrarTexto();"> 
        </div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si tienes cualquier duda, no dudes en consultármela.

Comment: Puedes usar el snippet de SOes... no es necesario que hagas el proceso en una página externa para este caso.

Comment: Cierto, lo cambio. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

así no me funciona tampoco pero poniendo

```
document.getElementById("textarea1").value = " ";
```

en vez de

```
document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";
```

si me funciona...